# How to remove XTerm button from the Icewm taskbar

Tags: icewm

I'm using preinstalled on opensuse icewm-lite as distraction-free environment, and already got rid of the menu/start button. Is there an option to disable XTerm button too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that global icewm config example `/etc/icewm/toolbar` had this button enabled. To overwrite it one must create empty `~/.icewm/toolbar` file.